# What is the normal mode vim command that converts false to FALSE as well as 12:48:03 AM to 12:48 simultaneously?

Tags: vim, vi

I accidentally performed a command in Normal mode in vim, on a TSV file, where it converted all the false to FALSE, all the true to TRUE, and all the times from 12:48:03 AM format to 12:48.

I believe it was a single command, because I could undo and redo it using 'u' and 'Ctrl-R', but I can't figure out what it was. Does anyone know?

If there is a Command Mode equivalent, I'd also be interested in learning about it, but I am trying to find the normal Mode version.

I have already tried q: and know that it is not a Command Mode command that I accidentally hit.

Comment: A plugin, maybe? An old macro? What plugins do you have?

Comment: Good suggestion, but it doesn't seem to be the case. I only source C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc and set relatively normal stuff like ts, sw, and ic.
It could be a Windows-specific thing, but that seems a little unlikely.

Comment: The problem, here is that the command executed would do a lot of unrelated things in one go. Did you try the search history (`q/`)?

Comment: I really suspect a clipboard replace operation... Could it be that you are looking at log files, the file has been overwritten **and** you have vim 7.3 persistent undo enabled? Even without `autoread` enabled it is quite easy to miss the 'reload' prompt and wonder why all your data changed.

Comment: That is possible, and I will investigate that possibility, although the only other tool I was working with at the time was awk.
I'm thinking it may be some kind of format toggle, akin to a filetype change kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

For changing the case of words you use `"gu"` and `"gU"` in normal mode.  Both need a scope, so he are some examples:

```
guu - make whole line lowercase
gUU - make whole line UPPERCASE
guw - make word lowercase
gUw - make word UPPERCASE
guj - make this and next line lowercase
gUk - make this line and previous line UPPERCASE
```

It also works with curent selections and is fully `"."` repeatable.  More can be found under [change](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#simple-change) in the vim docs.

Answer (score 0):

You know vim has that magic. Try this:

```
:%s/\(\d\d\:\d\d\)\:\d\d\ [A-P]M\|\(true\)\|\(false\)/\1\U\2\U\3/g
```

In case you need explanation please reply to the post and i will explain it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

`~` command does the following: Change the case of characters. This works both in visual and command mode. In visual mode, change the case of highlighted characters. In command mode, change the case of the character under cursor. This info is taken from [tuxfiles](http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/vimcheat.html)

Edit: I guess my reply is not totally answers your question, but may help you

Also, how do you relate this with `computer forensics`?

Comment: I didn't add computer-forensics. Someone else edited it to say that, I think.